# Как предать данные с объектом Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Вот цикл, который создает объекты Canvas и заполняет их данными из массива:

'''

```
    for product in products:
        if countColumn == int(width):
            countRow = countRow + 1
            countColumn = 0
        # bg = bgColor[str(product[9])]
        canvas = Canvas(self, width=300, height=150, bg=str(bgColor[str(product[9])]))
        canvas.grid(in_=contLIST, row=countRow, column=countColumn)
        canvas.create_text(5, 5, text=str(product[0]), anchor=NW, font="Verdana 12")   #, fill="green")
        canvas.create_text(200, 15, text=str(typeProd[str(product[12])]), justify=CENTER, font="Verdana 12")
        canvas.create_text(15, 35, text=product[3] + " " + product[4], anchor=W, font="Verdana 10 bold")
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("img/type" + str(product[12]) + ".png"))
        canvas.image = img
        canvas.create_image(50, 100, image=img)
        if str(product[10]) == "None":
            master = ""
        canvas.create_text(200, 70, text=master, font="Verdana 12")  # s[s.find(":") + 1:]
        canvas.create_text(200, 95, text=str(product[7])[str(product[7]).find(":") + 5:], font="Verdana 12 bold")
        canvas.create_text(200, 120, text=str(product[1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), font="Verdana 12")
        self.data = product[0]
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.openProduct(self.data))
        countColumn = countColumn + 1
```

'''

По клику мне нужно передать порядковый номер объекта, который отработал bind. Но lambda event у любого из созданных объектов Canvas отправляет только последний порядковый номер из массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался!
Для начала в строке `canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.openProduct(self.data))` вместо `self.data` нужно передать `event`.

команда event.widget возвращает порядковый номер виджета, по которому был клик. Преобразовал в строку, с помощью split отрезал порядковый номер виджета. Но у самого первого порядковый номер не ставится, поэтому пришлось 0 присваивать через условие.

```
    def openProduct(self, event):
        spl = str(event.widget).split("canvas")
        if spl[1] == "":
            canvaId = 0
        else:
            canvaId = int(spl[1] - 1)
        array = self.arrayOK[canvaId]
        print(array)
```